# 1 javascript file for more html files

Tags: javascript, html, architecture

I'd like to have 1 big controller javascript file for whole application. There are several html files. The problem is, after opening one of the html files, javascipt is raising error because it doesn't see elements of other html files. Any good suggestions to solve this?

Example of the code:

> app.js:

```
document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("control main");
});

document.querySelector(".minor").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("control minor");
});
```

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <button class="main"></button>
    <script type="module" defer src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> aside.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <button class="minor"></button>
    <script type="module" defer src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591385/can-a-single-javascript-file-be-used-by-multiple-html-files

Comment: it's different problem, I havn't problem with accessing js file, but how to correctly coordinate one js file and several html files

Comment: The only solution that I think is to add a switch statement on window.location.  
or you can also check if the element exists before binding the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create more than one js files, which respectively handle the html problems.
Or you should judge the elements's exist.
Such as:

```
const main = document.querySelector(".main");
if (main) {
  // to handle the problems
}
```